# Обработка события на сдвиг карты в 2Gis map SDK

Tags: android, map, 2gis-api

добавил в свой проект карту от 2Gis.
Подскажите, есть ли возможность отследить, когда пользователь сдвинул карту жестом, а когда это произошло из кода?